# Java, Jersey 1.17 & Jetty: Do not return stacktrace in response

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I was wondering if anyone could help with a problem I'm having...

At the minute, I'm running a rest service using Jersey 1.17 in a Jetty 8.1.10v20130312 container. If I do something wrong, say for example send a request with a content-type of "abcdefg", I get a response, however the stacktrace is included. I can see from the logs that the exception is an IllegalArgumentException wrapped in a WebApplicationException, but my WebApplicationException mapper is not handling it - I'm guessing that the exception is being thrown somewhere within Jetty, rather than my resource classes?

Is there a way to pre-empt or catch the error? Or a way to prevent the stacktrace from being included?

Any help would be much appreciated as usual!

Comment: `ExceptionMapper`s can only catch exceptions thrown by `@Path` annotated methods. The rest are mapped by the container.

Comment: Ah right I see, that has actually cleared up quite a bit of confusion then :)

Comment: A solution would be to register a Servlet `Filter` to intercept the response `OutputStream` and not commit it. When the servlet returns, check the `HttpServletResponse` status code, if it's a > 400, do something special like write out a different error message. You won't get the specific Exception object though.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you might be able to catch the exception in the `Filter` actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own page for handling errors in `web.xml` (because this seems to be an issue of Jetty rather than Jersey), i.e. for `HTTP 500` it would be:

```
<error-page>  
    <error-code>500</error-code>  
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

**Note:** I am not sure whether in this case Jersey wraps the `IllegalArgumentException` caused by the `ParsingException` (wrong media type of the response) into the `WebApplicationException`. The `IllegalArgumentException` is more likely passed to the underlying container (Jetty in this case) which handles it in it's own way.